# What is the word that expresses "the sound of a piece of metal hitting a hard object" (couldn't remember it, a "clan.." or something like that)?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

What is the word that expresses "**the sound of a piece of metal hitting a hard object**"?

It is often showed in movie subtitles.

I couldn't remember it, a "clan..." or "clas..." or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

As @KateBunting noted in the comments: *clang*:

> 1a: to make a loud metallic ringing sound
> anvils *clanged*

(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clang))

In general, if you know so many letters of the start of the word, even [online dictionaries can be browsed word for word](https://www.merriam-webster.com/browse/dictionary/c/47). I'm pretty sure you would have found it yourself.